# How to get the resolution of a movie sequence in VSE via python

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I added a movie to the sequencer with this code.
`filepath = /to/my/video/`

`mov = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie("Movie",filepath,1,1)`

I can access its **FPS**,**ColorSpace**,**Filepath**,**etc**. But I am unable to get its **Resolution** using python.

```
mov.fps
mov.filepath
mov.colorspace_settings.name
```

[image]

Comment: `x, y = mov.size`?

Comment: `mov.size  object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: It's in the `MovieSequence.elements`... take the first one (index 0) and you'll find `orig_width` and `orig_height`

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: If you switch on Dev extras under Preferences/Interface, you can right-click on an UI element and select Edit Source. This will open the python script in the Text Editor, and here you can see what and how an operator is called to display a certain feature. On getting the resolution, the playhead needs to be on the strip to make the resolution display correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original video resolution is in the `MovieSequence.elements`. Take the first one (index 0) and you'll find orig_width and orig_height.

A link to the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MovieSequence.html#bpy.types.MovieSequence.elements) and [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SequenceElement.html#bpy.types.SequenceElement.orig_height).

```
mov = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_movie("Movie",filepath,1,1)
 
element = mov.elements[0]

print(element.orig_width, element.orig_height)
```